# Set OnKeyListener function error

Tags: java, android

I have written code for setOnKeyListener to EditText widget in Android. But im gonna confusing why got error. The below is my code
[image: Error in setOnKeyListener]

I have followed tutorial from book. But it still error. Can you give me a solution?

Comment: what does eclipse says when you hover over the error ?

Comment: What error is descripted by the IDE?

Comment: The messages error like these:'Multiple markers at this line
 - The method setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener) in the type View is not applicable for the 
  arguments (new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener(){})
 - The type new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method 
  DialogInterface.OnKeyListener.onKey(DialogInterface, int, KeyEvent)'

Comment: @Martin Nordholts answer is correct

Comment: thanks a lot!i'm lack of thorough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are importing `android.content.DialogInterface.OnKeyListener`. What you want to import is `android.view.View.OnKeyListener`.

When you import `android.content.DialogInterface.OnKeyListener` Eclipse is trying to find a `setOnKeyListener` method in `EditText` that takes `android.content.DialogInterface.OnKeyListener` as a parameter, but such a method does not exist.